# How to include regex in Capybara table with pipe ('|') characters

Tags: capybara

This capybara table def in cucumber works:

```
And the developer adds these attributes:
| el_name        | value          |
| field_regex    | ^area_cd$      |
| default_format | text           |
```

This doesn't:

```
And the developer adds these attributes:
| el_name        | value           |
| field_regex    | ^(area|zip)_cd$ |
| default_format | text            |
```

The pipe character in the regex is breaking the table parse.  I've tried every mechanism of wrapping and escaping I can think of.  No joy.

Suggestions?

Comment: I advice you to post it to Cucumber mailing list. You will find better help to that question there

Comment: http://www.elabs.se/blog/15-you-re-cuking-it-wrong

Comment: actually michaeltwofish, i'm not.  the site is intended to support developers configure an interface, and the interface takes regex.  thanks for the comment, tho.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have just linked. You will get the most benefit from Cucumber by using it to describe your application and user interaction at a high level, with the detail in your step definitions. IMHO, your steps aren't very readable and therefore less useful and it would be better to describe the user's aim in the steps and have the matching regex in the definition.